# How do you remove standard padding of a Panel in AS3 feathers

Tags: actionscript-3, padding, starling-framework

I'm using AS3 with Starling and Feathers. While using the Panel from feathers I have noticed that it has standard padding(10px X, 22px Y). I have no idea how to remove this. If i give the childeren of the panel a negative location it still uses this padding. Does anyone know how i can get rid of this padding?

TY in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Panel` class inherits Scroller, which has a `padding` method. Try modifying it.

Also you may need to check out the theme, and find the initializer for Panel class. There you can set this `padding` value.

Comment: The default padding in the initalizer is "0", I have no clue how i can fix this.

Comment: Post some code. In my theme, the initializer has:

    panel.paddingTop = 0;
    panel.paddingRight = 8 * this.scale;
    panel.paddingBottom = 8 * this.scale;
    panel.paddingLeft = 8 * this.scale;

Comment: I'm using the default aeon desktop theme, where can i find this initialzer?

Comment: https://github.com/joshtynjala/feathers/blob/master/themes/AeonDesktopTheme/source/feathers/themes/BaseAeonDesktopTheme.as  line 1241